# How do you convert a quaternion into an axis-angle representation?

Tags: ros, bullet, quaternion, geometry-msgs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to convert an orientation from geometry_msgs::Quaternion to an axis-angle representation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle_representation). Similarly, I'd like to convert back to a quaternion from an axis-angle value. What ROS libraries are available to preform these conversions?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44250/how-do-you-convert-a-quaternion-into-an-axis-angle-representation?/) by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-09-20**:
I answered this question, then edited that and it disappeared. It does not allow me to answer again! The best I could do: https://gist.github.com/e5170cf046b8001f4e65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TF datatypes are actually re-cast Bullet Datatypes. If you have a tf::Quaternion, you can use any of the functions dejan linked to above, but specifically, you want these two:

[double btQuaternion::GetAngle()](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtQuaternion.html#a4071aa455c5850f651be8d49d3db7133)

[btVector3 btQuaternion::GetAxis()](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtQuaternion.html#a465718d2a4eb88eb0bd1ab98e73140c3)

When you want to change the value of a tf::Quaternion from an axis/angle representation, you can use this member function:

[void btQuaternion::SetRotation(const btVector3 &axis, const double &angle)](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtQuaternion.html#a395860d8fbccafdde50cd3ec5c6f4d58)

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6